# Forward Engineer in MySQL (Mac) generates extra tables

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

Whenever I am using the forward engineer feature of the mysql workbench for mac, it will generate extra tables on the output .sql file.

For example, in my model, I have 10 tables, after using the forward engineer feature, it will produce additional 5+ tables, sometimes repeating tables that already exist.

This happens randomly, sometimes it will generate the exact numbers that I needed and sometimes it will generate extra tables.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @Moritz - Got it, thanks.

Comment: I guess we will need more details here.  A step list that reproduces the problem would help a lot to see what's going on.